# PHP, posted value "0" in input causes to skip entire validation

Tags: php, forms, validation

First i thought that maybe `0` is accepted by script as demanded string beacuse letters dont have numeric value so they are considered `0` but than i have noticed that validation class isnt even runing when you type `0` to input field and submit it.
I also did the simple test, created most simple form with after post rule:

`if($_POST['confirm'] != 'YES') { produce error }`
and in simple environement like this it is working however in my application, typing `0` into confirm field causes to skip entire validation and exec's the syntax to db which is extremely weird.

This is file which holds the form and fires validation class upon submitting:

```
if(Input::exists('post')) {
    $validate = new Validate();
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'confirm' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'confirm' => true,
            'field_name' => 'Potwierdzenie'
        )
    ));

    if($validation->passed()) {
        //exec query
    } else {
        //display errors
    }
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="confirm">Type "YES" (without quotation marks) to confirm</label>
        <input type="text" name="confirm" id="confirm" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Usuń" />
</form>
```

now validation class that checks above conditions:

```
public function check($source, $items = array()) {
    foreach($items as $item => $rules) {
        foreach($rules as $rule => $rule_value) {

            $value = trim($source[$item]);

            if($rule === 'required' && strlen($value) === 0) {
                $this->addError("{$rules['field_name']} jest wymagany");
            } else {
                switch($rule) {
                    case 'confirm':
                        if($value != 'YES') {
                            $this->addError("{$rules['field_name']} wymaga wpisania \"YES\"");
                        }
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    if(empty($this->_errors)) {
        $this->_passed = true;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

additionaly:

```
class Validate {
    private $_passed = false,
            $_errors = array();

private function addError($error) {
    $this->_errors[] = $error;
}

public function errors() {
    return $this->_errors;
}

public function passed() {
    return $this->_passed;
}
```

now few facts:

- if i just click on submit it returns emptyness error
- if i type lets say 'dnedhned' or '23782372' it returns doesnt match error
- if i type 'YES' it is actualy completing check inside class and allowing exec
- if i type '0' it skipps validation part entirely and right away makes it passed

Does anyone has some idea why is that?

EDIT---------15.07.2014------21:32----

Solved problem was here:

```
if($rule === 'required' && strlen($value) === 0) {
$this->addError("{$rules['field_name']} jest wymagany");
} else {
```

This `} else {` must be changed to `} else if(strlen($value) !== 0) {`

and in some magic way `0` is no longer considered a term `YES`,

Comment: Could you show the actual code, not pseudo-code excerpts. It's impossible to tell what you're doing wrong without seeing it.

Comment: My first idea is that `0` is considerated by PHP like bool(false) in non-strict tests, maybe it's from here, but 'YES' and '0' or even bool(false) is realy not the same thing ... try `!==` maybe ...

Comment: @Bob0t The code he's shown so far doesn't use it in a boolean context. But maybe he's doing that in the code he hasn't shown.

Comment: @Barmar Yep, that's why i liked your com ^^ i want to see more too :P

Comment: as requested i gave you entire code, btw idea of `!==` doesnt matter as i said simple scenerio i described is working - meaning it blocks `0` value from being accepted as `YES`, in this script it demands `YES` and accepts `0` as well

Comment: What's the code for `$this->addError()` and `$validation->passed()`?

Comment: there you have, but there isnt really point to go through stuff like that, they just signify if no errors occured and if they have, they were add to errors[] array so they can be printed out

Comment: If it's just for a validation you can do a jquery UI popup ^^

Comment: nvm i solved problem on my own, thx for trying anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this also radio buttton

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="confirm">Select to confirm</label>
        YES <input input type="radio" checked="checked" name="confirm" value="YES" />
        NO <input input type="radio" name="confirm"value="NO" />
        </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Usuń" />
</form>
```

Comment: now its default send yes value  i hope that will work for you

Comment: This is not what i need, this topic is about value `0` being accepted by script as `YES`, structure must be preserved, i must find a reason why this `0` issue is happening, solution to that problem will be rewarded as +1